# PostgreSQL - generating an hourly list

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have an API that counts events from a table and groups them by the hour of day and severity that I use to draw a graph. this is my current query

```
SELECT
    extract(hour FROM time) AS hours,
    alarm. "severity",
    COUNT(*)
FROM
    alarm
WHERE
    date = '2019-06-12'
GROUP BY
    extract(hour FROM time),
    alarm. "severity"
ORDER BY
    extract(hour FROM time),
    alarm. "severity"
```

what I really want to do is get a list of hours from 00 to 24 with the corresponding event counts and 0 if there are no events that hour. is there a way to make postgres generate such a structure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `generate_series()` to generate the hours and a cross join for the severities:

```
SELECT gs.h, s.severity, COUNT(a.time)
FROM GENERATE_SERIES(0, 23, 1) gs(h) CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT DISTINCT a.severity FROM alarm
     ) s LEFT JOIN
     alarm a
     ON extract(hour FROM a.time) = gs.h AND
        a.severity = s.severity  AND
        a.date = '2019-06-12'
GROUP BY gs.h, s.severity
ORDER BY gs.h, s.severity;
```